# Toggle light bulb using relay or traditional switch button in parallel

Tags: circuit-design, solid-state-relay, homework

I'm working on my school project.
I want to control a light bulb using SSR relay (and nodemcu), but I also want to give user the option to toggle the light bulb using the traditional switch button which we generally have in our homes. The circuit diagram as below:

[image]

[image]

I'm stuck with this scenario: if the switch button is ON then relay would be of no use, it won't be able to turn off the light until I turn OFF the switch button.

This is the problem: I want to short circuit or disable the switch button line entirely whenever my relay is active.

Imagine you are lying on a bed, you are holding an Android phone and want to be able to command the relay to toggle light but the switch button is ON, but you are too tired to get up and turn off your switch button so that the relay can modify the state of light bulb.

Comment: As an alternative to the answer by @Vir, you could make the switch an input to the NodeMCU. It does not have to be in the path of the lightbulb as the NodeMCU already has control over the state of the light.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWyPwF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Looks like you already have a SPDT Relay, so now finish it off with a SPDT switch.  This is how two-way lights are done in homes so you shouldn't have trouble finding a wall switch that is SPDT.

Edit: find more about multiway switching [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching).

Comment: Thank you very much sir, but I wanted to control the light bulb either with the spdt relay or the traditinal SPST switch button . Im not sure if the disagram u have given is solving the problem . I wanted to give relay higher priority, so that whatever the state of switch, I want to be able to control the bulb using relay. Sorry for my beginner knowledge. ....In summary----Allow user to toogle the light bulb , either using the relay or the spst switch button.

Comment: Yes, that is what the circuit will do.

Comment: Thanks, but in my understanding , the curcuit has SPDT switch(SW1) .......I wanted to make use of SPST switch . is it correct ?

Comment: hello.. am I right ? is the circuit diagram using SPDT switch ?

Comment: Yes the circuit uses a SPDT switch but like I said, you can find SPDT switches that are designed to be used in homes like this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-3-Way-Toggle-Switch-White-R62-01453-02W/100356976

If for some reason you can't get or don't want to use an SPDT switch, do what @StarCat suggested and have the switch tie into your micro.

Comment: I wanted to use only SPST switch. Thank you @vir